# Emulator stops working after Android studio restarts

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Each time I restart my Android studio previously used Android emulator stops working. In case I run project emulator starts with black screen and Android studio waits forever when device come online.

If I create new emulated device everything goes fine till next restart. I was trying to push On button on emulator, but no reaction.

How to solve this problem?

Can I start Android emulator without Android studio? How?

[image]

Comment: Wipe your emulator data.

Comment: this is strange. What AS version you have? I just tested on my, newest and emulator stayed open

Comment: Having the exact same issue over here.